# Installed Oracle 19c. During install it did not ask for username/passwords. How do I sign into sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, passwords, default, sqlplus

It never asked for default passwords.  I have tried sysdba, sys, system. All ask for passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Start sqlplus with the User-Account, you had install Oracle. sqlplus should connect without username and password. After you are connected, you can ad new users.

```bash
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that:  sqlplus / as sysdba and it returns invalid username/password; logon denied.  I did the install myself on my own laptop signed in as myself.

Comment: Could you start sqlplus in the CLI? Type `sqlplus` and then type `connect / as sysdba`

Answer (score 0):

Try this on windows:

```
c:> sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect / as sysdba
SQL> alter user sys identified by ,new password>;
```

If you get asked for a password when you log in as / you need to create or recreate the password file using orapw. Check the $ORACLE_HOME/database directory for a file called orapw. That is the password file for the database. Create (or recreate) it using:

```
c:\> orawpd file=$ORACLE_HOME/database/orapwd<SID> password=<password> entries=5
```

[Lost SYS password Tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_lost_sysoper_password_in_oracle_10g_bc1.htm)

How do I find my Oracle 19c password? (Lost SYS password Tips)

1. login oracle user.
2. cd $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin.
3. ed(vi) file sqlnet.ora.
4. Remark by # at begining of line. SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE) => #SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
5. sqlplus /nolog or (svrmgrl) command.
6. connect sys as sysdba, or connect internal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this guides from the oracle doc side and others

[Reset the Password for the Oracle Database User](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E97665_01/html/rpm_81_userguide/GUID-1A32EA2F-69CE-465C-B069-822776B41EF3.htm)

[Resetting Your Oracle User Password with SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/resetting-your-oracle-user-password-with-sql-developer/)

How do I find my default username and password in Oracle?

> ORACLE creates a default account with the user ID "SYSADMIN" and
> password "SYSADMIN". It is best practice to remove default accounts,
> if possible. For accounts required by the system, the default password
> should be changed.

[Default ORACLE account SYSADMIN available](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/oracle-default-account-sysadmin/#:%7E:text=ORACLE%20creates%20a%20default%20account,default%20password%20should%20be%20changed.)

> SYSDBA is not a user, it is a system privilege. When you connect as / you are connecting to the SYS user. You don't need a password when you connect as you are - as long as it's a local connection from an OS account in the DBA group.

[SYSDBA password in Oracle DB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38701/sysdba-password-in-oracle-db)